# Unable to crawl ally.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm able to crawl webistes like nature.com, flipkart.com.It works just fine. but when I try to crawl ally.com, nike.com. it returns status code 403 and says undefined. Here is my code

```
// crawlerqueue.js

var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var URL = require('url-parse');
var pa11y=require('pa11y');

var START_URL = "http://www.nature.com/";
//var SEARCH_WORD = "stemming";
var MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT = 100;

var pagesVisited = {};
var numPagesVisited = 0;
var pagesToVisit = [];
var url = new URL(START_URL);
var baseUrl = url.protocol + "//" + url.hostname;

pagesToVisit.push(START_URL);
crawl();

function crawl() {
  if(numPagesVisited >= MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT) {
    console.log("Reached max limit of number of pages to visit.");
    return;
  }
  var nextPage = pagesToVisit.pop();
  if (nextPage in pagesVisited) {
    // We've already visited this page, so repeat the crawl
    crawl();
  } else {
    // New page we haven't visited
    visitPage(nextPage, crawl);
  }
}

function visitPage(url, callback) {
  // Add page to our set
  pagesVisited[url] = true;
  numPagesVisited++;

  // Make the request
  console.log("Visiting page " + url);
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
     // Check status code (200 is HTTP OK)
     console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
     if(response.statusCode !== 200) {
       callback();
       return;
     }
     // Parse the document body
     var $ = cheerio.load(body);
     /*var isWordFound = searchForWord($, SEARCH_WORD);
     if(isWordFound) {
       console.log('Word ' + SEARCH_WORD + ' found at page ' + url);
     } else*/ {
       collectInternalLinks($);
       // In this short program, our callback is just calling crawl()
       callback();
     }
  });
}

function searchForWord($, word) {
  var bodyText = $('html > body').text().toLowerCase();
  return(bodyText.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
}

function collectInternalLinks($) {
    var relativeLinks = $("a[href^='/']");
    console.log("Found " + relativeLinks.length + " relative links on page");
    relativeLinks.each(function() {
        pagesToVisit.push(baseUrl + $(this).attr('href'));
    });
}
```

I run this code through command line. Output for nature.com below:

```
Visiting page http://www.nature.com/
Status code: 200
Found 23 relative links on page
Visiting page http://www.nature.com/scitable/sponsors
Status code: 200
Found 22 relative links on page
Visiting page http://www.nature.com/scitable/pressnews
Status code: 200
Found 26 relative links on page
Visiting page http://www.nature.com/scitable/contact
Status code: 200
Found 26 relative links on page
Visiting page http://www.nature.com/scitable/about
Status code: 200
Found 25 relative links on page
Visiting page http://www.nature.com/scitable/my-profile/social-settings
Status code: 200
Found 22 relative links on page
Visiting page http://www.nature.com/scitable/photocredit
Status code: 200
Found 22 relative links on page
Visiting page http://www.nature.com/scitable/presscontact
Status code: 200
Found 26 relative links on page
Visiting page http://www.nature.com/scitable/presskit
Status code: 200
Found 26 relative links on page
Visiting page http://www.nature.com/scitable/pressroom
Status code: 200
Found 26 relative links on page
Visiting page http://www.nature.com/scitable/sponsorship
Status code: 200
Found 22 relative links on page
Visiting page http://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/copy-number-
Status code: 200
Found 89 relative links on page
Reached max limit of number of pages to visit.
```

but when I try to crawl nike.com or ally.com I get shown the below error

```
Visiting page http://www.ally.com
Status code: 403
Visiting page undefined
C:\Users\dashboard-master\node_modules\request\index.js:45
    throw new Error('undefined is not a valid uri or options object.')
    ^

Error: undefined is not a valid uri or options object.
    at request (C:\Users\dashboard-master\node_modules\request\
index.js:45:11)
    at visitPage (C:\Users\dashboard-master\config\crawlqueue.j
s:41:3)
    at crawl (C:\Users\dashboard-master\config\crawlqueue.js:30
:5)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\dashboard-master\config\crawlqueue.js:45:8)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\dashboard-master\node_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dashboard-master\node_modules\request\request.js:1171:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

> it returns status code 403

`ally.com` is behind Akamai Ghost Server, and Akamai prevents crawling somehow and also gives you an error reference.You can check this in the response body or returned headers under **X-Reference-Error** for me it looked like this **18.5fcxx917.148981xxxx.dacxsd6**. If you want to dig deeper you can look at their API's to translate error reference [here](https://developer.akamai.com/api/luna/diagnostic-tools/resources.html#translateerrorcode).

> and says undefined

First of all check for errors while making a request call. You are directly checking `response.statusCode` which you don't know whether you got a response or an undefined value.

In your case, you are calling `crawl` function and returning the execution if you don't have `200` success which means that you won't have **nextPages** to crawl.

```
var nextPage = pagesToVisit.pop();
```

here you are popping an empty array(pagesToVisit is empty because you didn't collect any links)so `nextPage` will be **`undefined`** and then you are passing the same as `uri` to request module which makes request module to throw an error.

What you can do is pop only when you have an array of length > 0 or check for nextPage value like this

```
if(nextPage){
    if (nextPage in pagesVisited) {
```